# executing claim rest call on JBPM return PermissionDeniedException

Tags: jbpm, redhat-bpm

I'm a JBPM newbie and I recently started playing with jBPM Workbench Showcase Docker image, and more specifically the hiring process. Everything works fine on the console, But when I tried to use JBPM rest API to control the process I got a PermissionDeniedException.

The error occurs when I want to claim a task using `[POST] /task/{taskId}/claim`. I got the following exception:

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
          <exception>
              <status>FAILURE</status>
              <url>http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/rest/task/1/claim</url>
              <message>PermissionDeniedException thrown with message 'User '[UserImpl:'admin']' does not have permissions to execute operation 'Claim' on task id 1'</message>
              <stackTrace>org.kie.remote.services.rest.exception.KieRemoteRestOperationException: User '[UserImpl:'admin']' does not have permissions to execute operation 'Claim' on task id 1
            at org.kie.remote.services.rest.exception.KieRemoteRestOperationException.internalServerError(KieRemoteRestOperationException.java:151)
            at org.kie.remote.services.cdi.ProcessRequestBean.doTaskOperation(ProcessRequestBean.java:418)
            at org.kie.remote.services.cdi.ProcessRequestBean.doRestTaskOperation(ProcessRequestBean.java:425)
            at org.kie.remote.services.cdi.ProcessRequestBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.doRestTaskOperation(Unknown Source)
            at org.kie.remote.services.rest.ResourceBase.doRestTaskOperationWithTaskId(ResourceBase.java:600)
            at org.kie.remote.services.rest.TaskResourceImpl.doTaskOperation(TaskResourceImpl.java:182)
            at org.kie.remote.services.rest.TaskResourceImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.doTaskOperation(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:395)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:202)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
            at org.kie.remote.services.rest.jaxb.DynamicJaxbContextFilter.doFilter(DynamicJaxbContextFilter.java:67)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.BasicAuthSecurityFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthSecurityFilter.java:78)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecureHeadersFilter.doFilter(SecureHeadersFilter.java:69)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecurityIntegrationFilter.doFilter(SecurityIntegrationFilter.java:57)
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
            at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
            at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
          Caused by: org.jbpm.services.task.exception.PermissionDeniedException: User '[UserImpl:'admin']' does not have permissions to execute operation 'Claim' on task id 1
            at org.jbpm.services.task.internals.lifecycle.MVELLifeCycleManager.evalCommand(MVELLifeCycleManager.java:119)
            at org.jbpm.services.task.internals.lifecycle.MVELLifeCycleManager.taskOperation(MVELLifeCycleManager.java:369)
            at org.jbpm.services.task.impl.TaskInstanceServiceImpl.claim(TaskInstanceServiceImpl.java:154)
            at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.ClaimTaskCommand.execute(ClaimTaskCommand.java:52)
            at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.ClaimTaskCommand.execute(ClaimTaskCommand.java:33)
            at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommandExecutorImpl$SelfExecutionCommandService.execute(TaskCommandExecutorImpl.java:65)
            at org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:41)
            at org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor.execute(TaskTransactionInterceptor.java:69)
            at org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:41)
            at org.drools.persistence.jta.TransactionLockInterceptor.execute(TransactionLockInterceptor.java:73)
            at org.drools.core.command.impl.AbstractInterceptor.executeNext(AbstractInterceptor.java:41)
            at org.drools.persistence.jpa.OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.execute(OptimisticLockRetryInterceptor.java:82)
            at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommandExecutorImpl.execute(TaskCommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
            at org.jbpm.services.task.impl.command.CommandBasedTaskService.execute(CommandBasedTaskService.java:157)
            at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.task.SynchronizedTaskService.execute(SynchronizedTaskService.java:851)
            at org.jbpm.kie.services.impl.UserTaskServiceImpl.execute(UserTaskServiceImpl.java:952)
            at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.UserTaskServiceCDIImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.execute(Unknown Source)
            at org.kie.remote.services.cdi.ProcessRequestBean.doTaskOperation(ProcessRequestBean.java:410)
            ... 62 more
          </stackTrace>
          </exception>
```

The thing I dont understand, I'm trying to claim the task using the user `katy`, but the error shows the the user `admin` does not have permission!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the exception it looks like 'admin' user is not part of group to which HumanTask is assigned. Only PotentialOwners of task can perform task operation. Check Task assignments and accordingly to that use correct user to perform task operation

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I totally agree with you, and I&#39;m not trying to perform task with the admin user, but instead I&#39;m using one from the eligible group (Katy in my case! Check image)! I don&#39;t know why it consider the call coming from `admin`

Comment: Looks like you arr using POSTMAN tool in google-chrome to send request and in browser you are logged into jbpm-console with admin user. If my understanding is correct then first logout admin user from browser and then try to execute REST API.

Comment: Oh no :/, you're right! tried the old simple curl command and it works like a charm. Something was wrong with Postman apparently. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar issue with the JBPM. It was a configuration for JbossEAP that was caching the credentials of the first user that logs into the application.Therfore, JBPM was using the same credentials to perform tasks operations for other users as well.

I removed the `cache-type="default"` in `<security-domain name="name" cache-type="default">` tag in standalone.xml.
It worked for me